Incompleteness of sub-$\sigma$-algebra when taking conditional expectation
Consider a complete probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{A}, P)$ and a sub-$\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{F}$ which is not complete, i.e. there exists $N \in \mathcal{A}$ satisfying $P(N)=0$ but $N \notin \mathcal{F}$. For some integrable random variable $X$, we consider the conditional expectation $E(X \, \vert \, \mathcal{F})$ which exists and is $P$-almost surely unique.
I am now wondering if there are any issues arising from the fact that $\mathcal{F}$ is not complete? We still know that the conditional expectation exists and is $P$-almost surely unique but I had a disucssion with someone stating that there are formal problems or that one has to be really careful when doing this. Can someone elaborate which kind of problems we are getting into if $\mathcal{F}$ is not complete?

Suppose, for a moment, that $\mathcal F$ is complete. Let $X$ be an integrable random variable and let $Y$ be a version of $E(X\mid\mathcal F)$. If $Z$ is a third random variable and $P(Z=Y)=1$, then $Z$ is another version of $E(X\mid\mathcal F)$ — the $\mathcal F$-measurability of $Z$ following from the completeness of $\mathcal F$. Without completeness, you can no longer come to such a conclusion.
